# How do I exclude everything with links from appearing in the pipes output?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

Yahoo Pipes is new to me and I want to know how to exclude tweets with links from appearing in the pipes output. I know filter can exclude everything with a keyword (say college) but I don't know how to exclude links.

I tried filter item.description that contains [each line with bit.ly, goo.gl] basically blocking everything with URL shortener. Is there a way to effectively block all links without having to enumerate all of them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I tried filter item.description that contains [each line with bit.ly, goo.gl] basically blocking everything with URL shortener

Comment: You should really update your q with what you have tried and where you are stuck. Makes it more likely that you will get an answer.